# iText character not shown

Tags: java, pdf, itext, quote, webdynpro

I'm working in java webdynpro. I've created a PDF with iText but not all character are shown in the pdf.

In my case I want to fill the field TextField17Place in my pdf with the value: D'entrée.

```
form.setField("TextField17Place", StandLocationString);
```

After creating the pdf, the field is filled but without the single quote.

Result: Dentrée

Do I need to implement a new font or is there a special code provided for single quote?

Comment: Can you share a SSCCE? See http://sscce.org if you don't know what I mean by this.